# matplotlib.pyplot fill_between shape error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to display a band using an upper and lower plots. but I keep getting an error. I am using matplotlib.pyplot fill_between.

Error Message:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (448, 1)

```
plt.xlim([0, 45.5])
plt.ylim([-16.50, 15.000])
plt.plot(len(X)-1, y_predicted, 'b', linewidth=1)

plt.fill_between(X, y_predit_lower, y_predit_upper, alpha=0.1, color='green')

plt.plot(X, y_predit_upper, 'g', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
plt.plot(X, y_predit_lower, 'g', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')

plt.axhline(y=10.70, color='r', linestyle='-.',linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 45.5, 1.0), fontsize=8)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-16.50, 15.00, 0.50), fontsize=8)
plt.title("Pressure Gradient Valve Size (27mm)")
plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
plt.ylabel("Pressure (mmHg)")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

For my x am using the values from a column of a DataFrame:
X = df_train['Time'].to_numpy('float')

This is the line of the code thats gives me the error:
plt.fill_between(X, y_predit_lower, y_predit_upper, alpha=0.1, color='green')

Error Message I get:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (448, 1)

```
In: print(X.shape)
Out: (448,)

In: print(y_predit_upper.shape)
Out: (448,)

In: print(y_predit_lower.shape)
Out: (448,)

In: print(X)
Out:
[ 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8
  2.9  3.   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.   4.1  4.2
  4.3  4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9  5.   5.1  5.2  5.3  5.4  5.5  5.6
  5.7  5.8  5.9  6.   6.1  6.2  6.3  6.4  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.8  6.9  7.
  7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4  7.5  7.6  7.7  7.8  7.9  8.   8.1  8.2  8.3  8.4
  8.5  8.6  8.7  8.8  8.9  9.   9.1  9.2  9.3  9.4  9.5  9.6  9.7  9.8
  9.9 10.  10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.  11.1 11.2
 11.3 11.4 11.5 11.6 11.7 11.8 11.9 12.  12.1 12.2 12.3 12.4 12.5 12.6
 12.7 12.8 12.9 13.  13.1 13.2 13.3 13.4 13.5 13.6 13.7 13.8 13.9 14.
 14.1 14.2 14.3 14.4 14.5 14.6 14.7 14.8 14.9 15.  15.1 15.2 15.3 15.4
 15.5 15.6 15.7 15.8 15.9 16.  16.1 16.2 16.3 16.4 16.5 16.6 16.7 16.8
 16.9 17.  17.1 17.2 17.3 17.4 17.5 17.6 17.7 17.8 17.9 18.  18.1 18.2
 18.3 18.4 18.5 18.6 18.7 18.8 18.9 19.  19.1 19.2 19.3 19.4 19.5 19.6
 19.7 19.8 19.9 20.  20.1 20.2 20.3 20.4 20.5 20.6 20.7 20.8 20.9 21.
 21.1 21.2 21.3 21.4 21.5 21.6 21.7 21.8 21.9 22.  22.1 22.2 22.3 22.4
 22.5 22.6 22.7 22.8 22.9 23.  23.1 23.2 23.3 23.4 23.5 23.6 23.7 23.8
 23.9 24.  24.1 24.2 24.3 24.4 24.5 24.6 24.7 24.8 24.9 25.  25.1 25.2
 25.3 25.4 25.5 25.6 25.7 25.8 25.9 26.  26.1 26.2 26.3 26.4 26.5 26.6
 26.7 26.8 26.9 27.  27.1 27.2 27.3 27.4 27.5 27.6 27.7 27.8 27.9 28.
 28.1 28.2 28.3 28.4 28.5 28.6 28.7 28.8 28.9 29.  29.1 29.2 29.3 29.4
 29.5 29.6 29.7 29.8 29.9 30.  30.1 30.2 30.3 30.4 30.5 30.6 30.7 30.8
 30.9 31.  31.1 31.2 31.3 31.4 31.5 31.6 31.7 31.8 31.9 32.  32.1 32.2
 32.3 32.4 32.5 32.6 32.7 32.8 32.9 33.  33.1 33.2 33.3 33.4 33.5 33.6
 33.7 33.8 33.9 34.  34.1 34.2 34.3 34.4 34.5 34.6 34.7 34.8 34.9 35.
 35.1 35.2 35.3 35.4 35.5 35.6 35.7 35.8 35.9 36.  36.1 36.2 36.3 36.4
 36.5 36.6 36.7 36.8 36.9 37.  37.1 37.2 37.3 37.4 37.5 37.6 37.7 37.8
 37.9 38.  38.1 38.2 38.3 38.4 38.5 38.6 38.7 38.8 38.9 39.  39.1 39.2
 39.3 39.4 39.5 39.6 39.7 39.8 39.9 40.  40.1 40.2 40.3 40.4 40.5 40.6
 40.7 40.8 40.9 41.  41.1 41.2 41.3 41.4 41.5 41.6 41.7 41.8 41.9 42.
 42.1 42.2 42.3 42.4 42.5 42.6 42.7 42.8 42.9 43.  43.1 43.2 43.3 43.4
 43.5 43.6 43.7 43.8 43.9 44.  44.1 44.2 44.3 44.4 44.5 44.6 44.7 44.8]

In: print(y_predit_upper.shape)
Out:
[-10.920185   -10.730879   -10.395649    -9.781197    -8.639384
  -6.6007776   -3.5282364   -0.28529644   2.1445403    3.7071989
   4.679699     5.2941465    5.695036     5.9663973    6.157011
   6.2958107    6.400445     6.4820027    6.5476484    6.6021276
   6.648663     6.6894903    6.72619      6.7599044    6.7914734
   6.821528     6.8505487    6.8789124    6.906917     6.934807
   6.962783     6.991015     7.01965      7.0488157    7.0786242
   7.1091766    7.140561     7.1728573    7.2061357    7.2404547
   7.275866     7.31241      7.3501153    7.389001     7.4290714
   7.4703183    7.512725     7.5562544    7.600858     7.646476
   7.6930337    7.740444     7.7886114    7.8374276    7.886779
   7.9365463    7.986604     8.036831     8.087101     8.137291
   8.187288     8.236979     8.286261     8.335035     8.383221
   8.430737     8.477519     8.52351      8.568661     8.61293
   8.65629      8.698717     8.740196     8.780713     8.82027
   8.858864     8.8965       8.933188     8.96894      9.003771
   9.037693     9.070728     9.102894     9.134211     9.1647
   9.19438      9.223274     9.251405     9.2787895    9.305452
   9.331414     9.356693     9.381311     9.405285     9.428637
   9.451382     9.47354      9.495129     9.516164     9.536662
   9.556641     9.576112     9.595093     9.613596     9.631638
   9.649229     9.666382     9.683111     9.69943      9.715345
   9.730873     9.746021     9.760802     9.775225     9.7893
   9.803036     9.8164425    9.829529     9.842304     9.854776
   9.866953     9.878841     9.890451     9.901789     9.912861
   9.923676     9.9342375    9.944555     9.954636     9.964481
   9.974102     9.983503     9.992689    10.001665    10.010438
  10.019011    10.0273905   10.03558     10.043587    10.051413
  10.059064    10.066545    10.07386     10.081012    10.088005
  10.094845    10.101532    10.108074    10.114471    10.120729
  10.126851    10.132839    10.138698    10.144428    10.150038
  10.155523    10.1608925   10.166145    10.171288    10.176319
  10.181244    10.186064    10.190783    10.1954      10.199922
  10.204349    10.20868     10.212924    10.217076    10.221144
  10.225128    10.229028    10.232847    10.236588    10.2402525
  10.243841    10.247356    10.2508      10.254173    10.257479
  10.2607155   10.263888    10.266995    10.270041    10.273026
  10.275951    10.278817    10.281626    10.284379    10.287078
  10.289722    10.292316    10.294858    10.297348    10.299793
  10.302189    10.304538    10.30684     10.309098    10.311312
  10.313485    10.315615    10.317703    10.319752    10.321762
  10.323734    10.325667    10.327566    10.329426    10.331253
  10.333044    10.334803    10.336527    10.338222    10.339883
  10.341513    10.343113    10.344685    10.346227    10.34774
  10.349226    10.350685    10.352116    10.353521    10.354902
  10.356257    10.357589    10.358896    10.36018     10.36144
  10.362679    10.363894    10.365089    10.366262    10.367414
  10.368546    10.369658    10.370752    10.371826    10.372882
  10.373919    10.374937    10.375938    10.376922    10.37789
  10.3788395   10.379774    10.380693    10.381596    10.3824835
  10.383356    10.384214    10.385057    10.385887    10.3867035
  10.387505    10.388294    10.3890705   10.3898325   10.390584
  10.391323    10.39205     10.392763    10.393466    10.394157
  10.394838    10.395506    10.396166    10.396815    10.397452
  10.398081    10.398699    10.399307    10.399906    10.400494
  10.401075    10.401647    10.402208    10.402762    10.403307
  10.403845    10.404373    10.404894    10.405405    10.4059105
  10.406408    10.4068985   10.40738     10.407856    10.408323
  10.408785    10.409239    10.409686    10.410128    10.410563
  10.410991    10.411414    10.411829    10.412239    10.412644
  10.413042    10.413435    10.413822    10.414204    10.414579
  10.414951    10.415317    10.415678    10.416034    10.416384
  10.416731    10.417071    10.417408    10.41774     10.418068
  10.418391    10.41871     10.4190235   10.419333    10.41964
  10.419942    10.42024     10.420534    10.420824    10.42111
  10.421393    10.421673    10.421947    10.422218    10.422487
  10.422752    10.423013    10.423271    10.423527    10.423778
  10.4240265   10.424272    10.424515    10.424753    10.42499
  10.425224    10.425454    10.425682    10.425907    10.426128
  10.426348    10.426565    10.426779    10.4269905   10.4272
  10.427407    10.427612    10.427814    10.428013    10.428211
  10.428406    10.428598    10.428788    10.428976    10.429163
  10.429345    10.429527    10.4297085   10.429886    10.430061
  10.430235    10.430407    10.430576    10.430744    10.43091
  10.431075    10.431237    10.431398    10.431557    10.431714
  10.4318695   10.432024    10.432177    10.432327    10.432476
  10.432623    10.43277     10.432913    10.433057    10.433199
  10.433338    10.433476    10.433613    10.433748    10.433882
  10.434015    10.434147    10.434278    10.434406    10.434532
  10.43466     10.434786    10.434908    10.43503     10.435152
  10.435272    10.43539     10.435509    10.435625    10.435741
  10.435854    10.435968    10.43608     10.436192    10.436301
  10.43641     10.436517    10.436625    10.43673     10.436835
  10.436939    10.437042    10.437143    10.437244    10.4373455
  10.437443    10.437542    10.437639    10.437736    10.437831
  10.437925    10.43802     10.438112    10.438204    10.438295
  10.438386    10.438476    10.438565    10.438652    10.438741
  10.438827    10.438912    10.438997    10.438997    10.438997
  10.438997    10.438997    10.438997    10.438997    10.438997
  10.438997    10.438997    10.438997  ]

In: print(y_predit_lower.shape)
Out:
[-1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01
 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01
 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4231827e+01 -1.4229019e+01
 -1.4225172e+01 -1.4219831e+01 -1.4212313e+01 -1.4201557e+01
 -1.4185902e+01 -1.4162625e+01 -1.4127128e+01 -1.4071282e+01
 -1.3980150e+01 -1.3825264e+01 -1.3550985e+01 -1.3048252e+01
 -1.2114041e+01 -1.0446091e+01 -7.9321928e+00 -5.2788787e+00
 -3.2908306e+00 -2.0122919e+00 -1.2166102e+00 -7.1388006e-01
 -3.8587976e-01 -1.6385698e-01 -7.9002380e-03  1.0566306e-01
  1.9127297e-01  2.5800228e-01  3.1171203e-01  3.5628605e-01
  3.9436054e-01  4.2776465e-01  4.5779157e-01  4.8537636e-01
  5.1120520e-01  5.3579545e-01  5.5953956e-01  5.8274651e-01
  6.0565925e-01  6.2847805e-01  6.5136743e-01  6.7446661e-01
  6.9789529e-01  7.2175813e-01  7.4614692e-01  7.7114415e-01
  7.9682255e-01  8.2324672e-01  8.5047436e-01  8.7855363e-01
  9.0752649e-01  9.3742609e-01  9.6827579e-01  1.0000916e+00
  1.0328760e+00  1.0666242e+00  1.1013203e+00  1.1369352e+00
  1.1734290e+00  1.2107525e+00  1.2488456e+00  1.2876358e+00
  1.3270454e+00  1.3669858e+00  1.4073639e+00  1.4480829e+00
  1.4890399e+00  1.5301342e+00  1.5712638e+00  1.6123290e+00
  1.6532354e+00  1.6938915e+00  1.7342124e+00  1.7741199e+00
  1.8135443e+00  1.8524213e+00  1.8906975e+00  1.9283261e+00
  1.9652677e+00  2.0014882e+00  2.0369649e+00  2.0716777e+00
  2.1056142e+00  2.1387653e+00  2.1711292e+00  2.2027068e+00
  2.2335000e+00  2.2635174e+00  2.2927685e+00  2.3212667e+00
  2.3490210e+00  2.3760500e+00  2.4023676e+00  2.4279904e+00
  2.4529357e+00  2.4772196e+00  2.5008607e+00  2.5238762e+00
  2.5462823e+00  2.5680971e+00  2.5893383e+00  2.6100211e+00
  2.6301632e+00  2.6497784e+00  2.6688843e+00  2.6874938e+00
  2.7056236e+00  2.7232871e+00  2.7404976e+00  2.7572689e+00
  2.7736154e+00  2.7895460e+00  2.8050761e+00  2.8202147e+00
  2.8349762e+00  2.8493690e+00  2.8634038e+00  2.8770909e+00
  2.8904424e+00  2.9034648e+00  2.9161687e+00  2.9285626e+00
  2.9406557e+00  2.9524565e+00  2.9639721e+00  2.9752111e+00
  2.9861798e+00  2.9968877e+00  3.0073400e+00  3.0175438e+00
  3.0275064e+00  3.0372334e+00  3.0467329e+00  3.0560083e+00
  3.0650678e+00  3.0739164e+00  3.0825577e+00  3.0909996e+00
  3.0992465e+00  3.1073031e+00  3.1151748e+00  3.1228657e+00
  3.1303816e+00  3.1377258e+00  3.1449032e+00  3.1519175e+00
  3.1587734e+00  3.1654744e+00  3.1720252e+00  3.1784282e+00
  3.1846886e+00  3.1908092e+00  3.1967940e+00  3.2026453e+00
  3.2083673e+00  3.2139630e+00  3.2194352e+00  3.2247872e+00
  3.2300220e+00  3.2351422e+00  3.2401505e+00  3.2450500e+00
  3.2498436e+00  3.2545323e+00  3.2591219e+00  3.2636104e+00
  3.2680025e+00  3.2723012e+00  3.2765074e+00  3.2806249e+00
  3.2846537e+00  3.2885976e+00  3.2924585e+00  3.2962365e+00
  3.2999353e+00  3.3035574e+00  3.3071012e+00  3.3105736e+00
  3.3139715e+00  3.3172994e+00  3.3205595e+00  3.3237495e+00
  3.3268752e+00  3.3299356e+00  3.3329334e+00  3.3358698e+00
  3.3387456e+00  3.3415632e+00  3.3443227e+00  3.3470273e+00
  3.3496766e+00  3.3522720e+00  3.3548145e+00  3.3573065e+00
  3.3597488e+00  3.3621411e+00  3.3644867e+00  3.3667846e+00
  3.3690367e+00  3.3712454e+00  3.3734097e+00  3.3755307e+00
  3.3776112e+00  3.3796487e+00  3.3816485e+00  3.3836088e+00
  3.3855305e+00  3.3874140e+00  3.3892622e+00  3.3910737e+00
  3.3928509e+00  3.3945937e+00  3.3963022e+00  3.3979788e+00
  3.3996229e+00  3.4012361e+00  3.4028187e+00  3.4043717e+00
  3.4058938e+00  3.4073887e+00  3.4088535e+00  3.4102931e+00
  3.4117036e+00  3.4130898e+00  3.4144497e+00  3.4157834e+00
  3.4170928e+00  3.4183784e+00  3.4196396e+00  3.4208779e+00
  3.4220929e+00  3.4232869e+00  3.4244580e+00  3.4256082e+00
  3.4267378e+00  3.4278469e+00  3.4289360e+00  3.4300056e+00
  3.4310555e+00  3.4320869e+00  3.4331002e+00  3.4340954e+00
  3.4350724e+00  3.4360318e+00  3.4369760e+00  3.4379010e+00
  3.4388113e+00  3.4397054e+00  3.4405851e+00  3.4414482e+00
  3.4422965e+00  3.4431300e+00  3.4439492e+00  3.4447536e+00
  3.4455457e+00  3.4463229e+00  3.4470873e+00  3.4478393e+00
  3.4485774e+00  3.4493046e+00  3.4500179e+00  3.4507203e+00
  3.4514103e+00  3.4520888e+00  3.4527564e+00  3.4534125e+00
  3.4540586e+00  3.4546938e+00  3.4553175e+00  3.4559317e+00
  3.4565368e+00  3.4571309e+00  3.4577150e+00  3.4582901e+00
  3.4588556e+00  3.4594121e+00  3.4599595e+00  3.4604993e+00
  3.4610300e+00  3.4615517e+00  3.4620652e+00  3.4625711e+00
  3.4630685e+00  3.4635587e+00  3.4640403e+00  3.4645157e+00
  3.4649830e+00  3.4654431e+00  3.4658966e+00  3.4663415e+00
  3.4667811e+00  3.4672141e+00  3.4676394e+00  3.4680586e+00
  3.4684715e+00  3.4688792e+00  3.4692798e+00  3.4696741e+00
  3.4700637e+00  3.4704461e+00  3.4708233e+00  3.4711957e+00
  3.4715614e+00  3.4719224e+00  3.4722786e+00  3.4726286e+00
  3.4729748e+00  3.4733148e+00  3.4736505e+00  3.4739819e+00
  3.4743066e+00  3.4746289e+00  3.4749455e+00  3.4752569e+00
  3.4755650e+00  3.4758687e+00  3.4761677e+00  3.4764628e+00
  3.4767542e+00  3.4770417e+00  3.4773250e+00  3.4776039e+00
  3.4778790e+00  3.4781504e+00  3.4784188e+00  3.4786835e+00
  3.4789438e+00  3.4792008e+00  3.4794540e+00  3.4797049e+00
  3.4799519e+00  3.4801960e+00  3.4804363e+00  3.4806743e+00
  3.4809079e+00  3.4811401e+00  3.4813676e+00  3.4815922e+00
  3.4818144e+00  3.4820347e+00  3.4822516e+00  3.4824648e+00
  3.4826765e+00  3.4828849e+00  3.4830904e+00  3.4832940e+00
  3.4834948e+00  3.4836936e+00  3.4838891e+00  3.4840827e+00
  3.4842734e+00  3.4844618e+00  3.4846487e+00  3.4848323e+00
  3.4850144e+00  3.4851933e+00  3.4853716e+00  3.4855466e+00
  3.4857192e+00  3.4858909e+00  3.4860601e+00  3.4862275e+00
  3.4863930e+00  3.4865561e+00  3.4867177e+00  3.4868770e+00
  3.4870348e+00  3.4871902e+00  3.4873438e+00  3.4874964e+00
  3.4876461e+00  3.4877954e+00  3.4879422e+00  3.4880881e+00
  3.4882312e+00  3.4883738e+00  3.4885139e+00  3.4886527e+00
  3.4887900e+00  3.4889264e+00  3.4890614e+00  3.4891939e+00
  3.4893255e+00  3.4894552e+00  3.4895840e+00  3.4897108e+00
  3.4898376e+00  3.4899626e+00  3.4900851e+00  3.4902072e+00
  3.4903274e+00  3.4904480e+00  3.4905648e+00  3.4906826e+00
  3.4907985e+00  3.4909120e+00  3.4910259e+00  3.4911375e+00
  3.4912481e+00  3.4913583e+00  3.4914665e+00  3.4915743e+00
  3.4916811e+00  3.4917865e+00  3.4918904e+00  3.4919934e+00
  3.4920964e+00  3.4921975e+00  3.4922967e+00  3.4923968e+00
  3.4924951e+00  3.4925923e+00  3.4926887e+00  3.4927831e+00
  3.4928784e+00  3.4929719e+00  3.4930644e+00  3.4931564e+00
  3.4932475e+00  3.4933367e+00  3.4934263e+00  3.4935131e+00
  3.4936023e+00  3.4936886e+00  3.4937744e+00  3.4938593e+00
  3.4939427e+00  3.4940267e+00  3.4941092e+00  3.4941907e+00
  3.4942718e+00  3.4943528e+00  3.4944315e+00  3.4945107e+00
  3.4945889e+00  3.4946666e+00  3.4947433e+00  3.4948187e+00]
```

Dont know what I am missing here with the data structure.

Comment: Your error seems to come from the line `plt.plot(len(X)-1, y_predicted)`. It's quite unclear what that line is meant to do.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC you were right the error was generated at that line of code. I was chasing tails trying to fix the fill between line.